# Add custom text automatically on each post

Tags: posts, functions, loop

Suppose I have a post and it's the first paragraph is:

"**This a Pen. The color is red**."

I want to add a custom text like "2022" after "Pen" on first sentence, at the end of the text line.

Example: "**This a Pen, *2022*. The color is red**."

I need to add this to all of the posts automatically. Is there a way to do that?
Or do I have to replace in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to sniff for it on the `the_content` filter.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse403518_custom_text' );
function wpse403518_custom_text( $content ) {
    $regex   = '/^([^\.!?]+)([\.!?])(.*)$/';
    $replace = '$1 2022$2$3';
    $content = preg_replace( $regex, $replace, $content );
    return $content;
}
```

### The regex

The `$regex` variable is a [regular expression](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php), and what it does, roughly, is this:

- `^` means the start of the string; then
- `([^\.!?]+)` means "match everything that is *not* a `.`, `!`, or `?` one or more times" (ie, the first sentence, until we hit a `.`, `!`, or `?`); then
- `([\.!?])` means "match a single `.`, `!`, or `?`" (ie, the first sentence-ending punctuation in the string); then
- `(.*)` means "all the characters"; then
- `$` means "the end of the string".

The `$replace` variable assigns `$1` to the first group above (the first sentence), `$2` to the second group (ie, the first `.`, `!`, or `?`), and `$3` to the third group (ie, the rest of the content). So what happens is that the  `2022` gets inserted between the first sentence and the punctuation at its end, then the rest of the text gets printed as normal.

### References

- [`the_content` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/)
- [`preg_replace()`](https://php.net/preg_replace)